# What is the flags arg in Finagle Memcached set method

Tags: memcached, finagle

`com.twitter.finagle.memcached.Client` defined the set method as

```
set(key: String, flags: Int, expiry: Time, value: T): Future[Unit]
```

What should the flags be? Is there any documentation available for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from: http://docs.libmemcached.org/memcached_set.html

> “flags” is a 4byte space that is stored alongside of the main value.
>   Many sub libraries make use of this field, so in most cases users
>   should avoid making use of it.